# Horizontal list - bullet equal distance/centered between list items

Tags: html, css

I would like the bullet in my horizontal list to be in the middle/center between each list item.  i want that bullet to be centered between each item

Here is my css code:

```
.tags-mid {
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}

.tags-mid ul {
       font-size: 25px;
       font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.tags-mid li {
       display: inline;
       line-height: 25px;
       padding-right: 20px;
       padding-left: 20px;
}

.tags-mid li:after {

       content: " · ";
}

.tags-mid li:last-child:after {
       content: "";
}

.tags-mid a {
    color: #000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.tags-mid a:hover {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle and post it : http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try applying your `padding` to the `:after` pseudo element rather than to your list items. Here is a link to a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GeD4K/